# Can't connect to my server/instance with my Terraform Code for AWS Firewall Project

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, vpc, infrastructure-as-code

I am new in learning Terraform and currently creating a project. The architecture I'm trying to implement is this.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "InspectionVPC" {
    cidr_block = "10.1.0.0/16"
    instance_tenancy = "default"
    enable_dns_hostnames = "true"
    enable_dns_support = "true"

    tags = {
        Name = "FW Inspection VPC"
    }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "FirewallSubnet" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.InspectionVPC.id
    cidr_block = "10.1.1.0/28"
    map_public_ip_on_launch = true
    availability_zone = "us-east-1a"

    tags = {
        Name = "Firewall Subnet"
    }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "ProtectedWebServerSubnet" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.InspectionVPC.id
    cidr_block = "10.1.3.0/28"
    availability_zone = "us-east-1a"

    tags = {
        Name = "Protected WebServer Subnet"
    }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "InspectionVPCInternetGateway" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.InspectionVPC.id

    tags = {
      Name = "Inspection VPC IGW"
    }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "FirewallRouteTable" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.InspectionVPC.id
    route {
        cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
        gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.InspectionVPCInternetGateway.id
        }

        tags = {
            Name = "Firewall Route Table"
        }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "FirewallRouteTableAssociation" {
    subnet_id = aws_subnet.FirewallSubnet.id
    route_table_id = aws_route_table.FirewallRouteTable.id
}

resource "aws_security_group" "allow_httpssh" {
  name        = "allow_httpssh_traffic"
  description = "Allow http & ssh inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.InspectionVPC.id

  ingress {
    description = "HTTP"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["180.191.165.6/32"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "SSH"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["180.191.165.6/32"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "Allow HTTP & SSH traffic"
  }
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "web-server-nic" {
    subnet_id       = aws_subnet.ProtectedWebServerSubnet.id
    private_ips     = ["10.1.3.4"]
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.allow_httpssh.id]
}

resource "aws_eip" "ec2_eip" {
    instance                  = aws_instance.WebServer.id
    vpc                       = true
    network_interface         = aws_network_interface.web-server-nic.id
    associate_with_private_ip = "10.1.3.4"
    depends_on                = [aws_internet_gateway.InspectionVPCInternetGateway]
}

resource "aws_instance" "WebServer" {
  ami = "ami-0f844a9675b22ea32"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  key_name = "Project-Key-Pair"

  network_interface {
    device_index         = 0
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.web-server-nic.id
  }

  user_data = <<-EOF
                #!/bin/bash
                sudo amazon-linux-extras install nginx1 -y
                sudo systemctl enable nginx
                sudo systemctl start nginx
                EOF

  tags = {
    Name = "Test Workload"
  }
}

output "WebServer_Public_IP" {
  value = aws_eip.ec2_eip.public_ip
}
```

Followed exactly the steps on this link: [Hands-on Network Firewall Workshop](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/d071f444-e854-4f3f-98c8-025fa0d1de2f/en-US/lab-one/step-two) from **Lab One: Protected VPC with Public Workload > Create firewall > Create route tables** to add the routing to and from firewall, IGW and Protected subnet via AWS Management Console.

However, I really can't connect to the **EC2 Instance Connect** or **PuTTY SSH** client (**Connection timeout** error) with my key pair. I even created an **SSM Instance Profile** with the below permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:DescribeAssociation",
                "ssm:GetDeployablePatchSnapshotForInstance",
                "ssm:GetDocument",
                "ssm:DescribeDocument",
                "ssm:GetManifest",
                "ssm:GetParameter",
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:ListAssociations",
                "ssm:ListInstanceAssociations",
                "ssm:PutInventory",
                "ssm:PutComplianceItems",
                "ssm:PutConfigurePackageResult",
                "ssm:UpdateAssociationStatus",
                "ssm:UpdateInstanceAssociationStatus",
                "ssm:UpdateInstanceInformation"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel",
                "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2messages:AcknowledgeMessage",
                "ec2messages:DeleteMessage",
                "ec2messages:FailMessage",
                "ec2messages:GetEndpoint",
                "ec2messages:GetMessages",
                "ec2messages:SendReply"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But still the same. I'm thinking the problem is related with my security group or EC2 instance. So after running the code, I created separate security group and ec2 instance allowing any IPv4 addresses to connect for all traffic. However, the same issue persists. Anyone knows what wrong with my IaC?

Comment: Did you try attaching the security group `allow_httpssh` directly to the aws_instance ?

Answer (score 0):

In your AWS EC2 Instance Resource, I don't see the security group attached anywhere which is your EC2 Instance's Firewall.

```
resource "aws_instance" "WebServer" {
  ami = "ami-0f844a9675b22ea32"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  key_name = "Project-Key-Pair"

  network_interface {
    device_index         = 0
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.web-server-nic.id
  }

  user_data = <<-EOF
                #!/bin/bash
                sudo amazon-linux-extras install nginx1 -y
                sudo systemctl enable nginx
                sudo systemctl start nginx
              EOF

  tags = {
    Name = "Test Workload"
  }
  # attach security group:
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.allow_httpssh.id]
}
```